# Yup date validation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, yup

I'm using Vuelidate and I want to use Yups validation rules. I'm trying to validate a date in string format:

component:

```
<label class="flex flex-col p p--sm text-gray-500">Beschikbaar (datum)
  <input
    v-model="form.date"
    class="p-aanmelden__email"
    @blur="$v.form.date.$touch"
  >
</label>
<p v-if="$v.form.date.$error">
  Enter a valid date
</p>

data () {
  return {
    form: {
      date: ''
    }
  }
},
validations: {
  form: {
    date: { required, customDate }
  }
},
```

validationHelpers.js:

```
import * as yup from 'yup'

export const customDate = async (value) => {
  const schema = yup.date()
  console.log(await schema.isValid(value))
  return await schema.isValid(value)
}
```

If I type `1` into the corresponding field the log returns `true` if I type a letter `a` it's false. But I would expect the value to be checked against a date format, and 1 is not a correct date format so the `schema.isValid` should be false, but it's returning true.